# Get URL from Webhook's POST and download the file

Tags: file, url, download

I have Webhook from another system, that has POST data looking like this:

```
{
       "eventType":"OrderGenerated",
       "data":{
          "orderCode":"000000283",
          "orderAmount":7.9,
          "orderDate":"2018-06-08T08:47:30.17",
          "orderDetails":[
             {
                "detailCode":"1912",
                "detailDesignDocId":"xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx",
                "detailCustomerId":0,
                "detailVisitorId":36542,
                "detailQuantity":1,
                "detailPrice":7.9,
                "detailModelName":"T-Shirt",
                "detailModelCode":"BCTM010",
                "detailFiles":[
                   {
                      "variantName": "Red",
                      "sideName":"Front",
                      "areaID":1,
                      "format":"svg",
                      "fileUrl":"....svg"
                   },
                   ...
                ]
             }
          ]
       }
    }
```

I need to take "fileUrl" and download that file to FTP. I have no idea where to start, let's say I'd make a webhook in php, but how can I point to "fileUrl" to download file from? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide explanation what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I have POST data which I've posted from system called "Zakeke", and I'm trying to download the file that Zakeke gives url for in POST data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the guy working at Zakeke who made the webhooks.

You just need to use the HTTP client that your environment provides to you. If you are using PHP then just use Guzzle or CURL, if you are in a C# environment, just use the WebClient class.

Comment: Ha. Small world. Problem is, I'm really a newbie at the whole coding thing. I suppose I'd use something like this?: http://prntscr.com/v6twjm - Problem is, I have no idea how to point out to "fileUrl" from POST, since it's all in arrays and there's multiple of them: http://prntscr.com/v6twx6 Any help here? Thanks.